# Simple program in C doesn't work

Tags: c, interactive

I'm new to C and I'm currently making a tutorial.

I have decided to combine two exercices and I want to take inputs
as long as I don't just do < return >. This is my code until now:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char letter;
int i=0;

int main() {
  while (i==0) {
    printf(">> ");
    letter = getchar();
    printf("%d\n", letter);
    if (letter==10) {     //10 is the ASCII id for <return>
      printf("End\n");
      i = 1;
    }
    printf("You've entered %c\n", letter);
  }
}
```

The problems is that when I enter a letter for the first time, it does what I want it to do: take a number, and return it on the screen. Directly after that it sets 10 **on it's on own**!

This is the output:

```
>> r //I've entered 'r'
114
Das Zeichen ist r
>> 10 //I've entered nothing. It entered that on it's own
End
The letter is
```

What is going on here? Why does it do that? I didn't enter anything or pressed anything.

Comment: You never assign a value to `zeichen`. What it is supposed to be? I guess letter and zeichen are supposed to be the same variable since you don't even declare zeichen.

Comment: yeah I'm german I forgot to translate I've edited the post

Comment: you made one edit... but is the "zeichen" in the if statement also supposed to be "letter"?

Comment: Note to clarify: You are not "making" a tutorial, but "follow" one.

Comment: Sorry, as mentioned I'm german and my english is not the best

Comment: @Mr.Squiddy That's why I well understood what you mean :-) Just tried to help improving you post, not meant offending.

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char` for a good reason: provide out-of-band signalling through negative values, e.g. `EOF`.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like you to tell which tutorial you're following if it recommends to use `char` with `getchar()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that when you enter `"r"` you also press Enter (`'\n'` which equals to ASCII 10). The shortest way is to add another `getchar()` inserted to consume the '\n':

```
int main() {
  while (i==0) {
    printf(">> ");
    letter = getchar();
    getchar();
    printf("%d\n", letter);
    if (zeichen==10) {     //10 is the ASCII id for <return>
      printf("End\n");
      i = 1;
    }
    printf("You've entered %c\n", letter);
  }
}
```

There is also another short way which is comparing letter value early after it's assignment like following:

```
int main() {
  while (i==0) {
    printf(">> ");
    letter = getchar();
    if(letter == '\n')
       continue;
    printf("%d\n", letter);
    if (zeichen==10) {     //10 is the ASCII id for <return>
      printf("End\n");
      i = 1;
    }
    printf("You've entered %c\n", letter);
  }
}
```

however you still need to assign `zeichen` to something otherwise you'll get undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

Standard portable C API are not good to handle keystrokes. To "enter r" you need to press "r" "return" so your program using `getchar()` will receive them both immediately. Your need to use [ncurses](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) or [cornio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h).

Comment: So how do I do that? (I'm a complete noob at C)

Comment: @Mr. Squiddy If your system is linux you need to include "ncurses.h" and read documentation. If your system is windows maybe ncurses also exist for Windows (but I am not sure), but I am sure cornio exists: https://sourceforge.net/projects/myconio/

Answer (score 0):

`while (i==0) {
    printf(">> ");
    letter = getchar();
    printf("%d\n", letter);
    if (zeichen==10) {     //10 is the ASCII id for <return>
      printf("End\n");
      break;
    }`

Use `break` statement instead of `i=1;`

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows, use `_getch()` from "conio.h"

Also, instead of checking for `10` (which is the linefeed character not Return), it is better to check for `\r`, which is what the ENTER key returns. Never use literal values when more descriptive escapes can be used:

- line feed = `\n`
- Return = `\r`

etc.